# how can I check each li text color in ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the text color of `<li>` one by one when I click the change button. Once all the `<li>` text is red it'll show the alert message "all li text color changed!".

My html code is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="change">change li text-color</button>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
      <li>six</li>
      <li>seven</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my script is (jquery v1.5.2):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $('#change').click(function ()
  {
    $('#nav li').each(function ()
    {
        $(this).css('color', '#F00');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: whats wrong here ? the code is fine

Comment: @RoyiNamir too localized

Comment: see i want to change the li color one by one,like when first time click first li ,second click second li like that, but when i click first time the whole li color changing, i don't want that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want change colors one by one with each click.
Add a counter:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  var len = $('#nav li').length,
      cnt = 0;
  $('#change').click(function ()
  {
    if (cnt < len)
    {
      $('#nav li:eq('+cnt+')').css('color', '#F00');
      cnt++;
    } else {
      alert("all li text color changed!");
    }
  });
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SUtED/